# Are recent versions of ASP.NET implementing proper authenticated encryption?

Tags: cryptography, asp.net

There has been uncovered before that ASP.Net does not use the authenticated encryption right (e.g. [here](http://netifera.com/research/poet/ieee-aspnetcrypto.pdf)), they used Mac-then-encrypt that lead to some practical attacks. So I am wondering if I use `FormsAuthentication.Encrypt()` now (with latest patches to asp.net 4), will it use the proper Encrypt-then-MAC?

Comment: -1 as I believe the answer is in the paper you link to: "After we sent more information to Microsoft, they eventually released a patch that did prevent all of our attacks" They refer to https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms10-070

Comment: I saw this link, but I have read the fix and it seems they have fixed the padding oracle and some other problems, but I have not seen in the bulletin that they have updated the way they do MAC now, nor have I found it in the documentation.

Comment: Do you mean: did they switch from mac-then-encrypt to encrypt-then-mac, or what problem with the MAC are you talking about? I think it would be worth it to update your question with a more exact explanation.

Comment: Changed the question to ask only about the MAC, otherwise it is fixed as you say with reference in the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormsAuthentication.Encrypt()` now uses the encrypt-the-MAC pattern over both the IV and the ciphertext, so yes, it is done correctly now.

As a side note, it does depend on the machinekey element to determine which encryption and MAC algorithms are used, it's worth double-checking your configuration to ensure you're configured to use either AES or Auto (which resolves to AES) and not DES (weak) or TripleDES (slow).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I know about the machineKey configuration and it is set up to use AES and SHA1 (which is HMACSHA1). I am just not sure how to set up the key length, but I guess it uses maximum possible, i.e. if the value at least 192, then 192 is used for AES.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik It will determine the correct AES variant based on the length of the key in your configuration, much as you suspect.   If you create a 192-bit key, it will use AES-192, if you use a 256-bit key, then you'll get AES-256.   I believe (but am not certain, off the top of my head) that any size other than 128, 192, or 256 will throw an invalid key size error, rather than truncating it to the largest compatible size.   That would be easy to test.